# Unable to uninstall Trellix ENS - One or more products are dependent on this product

Tags: security

I'm unable to uninstall Trellix ENS as I get the error message:

> One or more products are dependent on this product"

but actually there's no other module.

**Trellix ENS:**

[image: Trellix ENS]

**Uninstall error message:**

[image: Uninstall error message]

**Installation folder:**

[image: Installed Folder]

Is there a solution to uninstalling Trellix ENS?

Comment: Welcome to Stack, @Itsarapong  I think you'll get better results asking this on [su], since Stack Overflow is more for questions about programming.

Comment: 1st Google result: https://kcm.trellix.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB83456